# $c_0$, the space of sequences converging $0$ is complete with dual $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $c_0$ be the space of all complex sequences $(a_n)$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| =0$$  with norm $\|(a_n)\|_{c_0} = \sup_{n} |a_n|$.

Is it fair to say that:

Let $\{(a_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a cauchy sequence in $c_0$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists $N$ such that for $n,m \geq N$, 
$$\|(a_n) - (a_m)\|_{c_0} = \sup_{k} |a_{n,k}-a_{m,k}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
Let $n_0 \geq N$. Notice also that since $(a_{n_0}) \in c_0$, there exists $K$ such that, for $k \geq K$, $|a_{n_0,k}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Therefore, define $(a) \in c_0$ as the sequence $a_k = a_{n_0,k}$ for $k < K$ and $a_k = 0$ for $k \geq K$. Then for $n_0$ as before and  $m \geq N$, $\|(a_m)-(a)\|_{c_0} \leq \|(a_m)-(a_{n_0}) \|_{c_0} +  \|(a_m)-(a_{n_0}) \|_{c_0} < \epsilon$. Thus, $\{(a_n)\}$ converges so $c_0$ is complete.  ?

I was unsure about this proof since it seems that the cauchy sequence could converge to different limits, but I suppose in the uniform norm of $c_0$, the limits would only differ by $\epsilon$ so the limit is unique.

Finally I need to show that $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ is the dual space of $c_0$. Is it correct to say that, given $(x_n) \in \ell^1$, I want the action of $$(x_n) : c_0 \to \mathbb{C}$$ to be defined as $$(x_n): (a_n) \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n\overline{a_n}?$$ This clearly converges by comparison, and I'm left to show that all such linear functionals arise this way. It seems prudent to say that a linear functional on $(a_n) \in c_0$ can be determined by it's action on finite truncations of $(a_n)$, and therefore can be identified with some element in $$\operatorname{span}\{e_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$$ for $e_i$ the orthonormal hilbert basis for $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$. A **very slight hint** on how to proceed with this would be appreciated, but please please only a slight hint. I want to proceed on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right to be skeptical; your limit $a$ does not work. Hint: Knowing that
$$ \sup_k |a_{n,k} - a_{m,k}| → 0$$
means that for each $k$, $a_{n,k}∈ℝ $ is a ...

Proof that the map $\phi: \ell^1 → c_0^*$ given by $T(x)(a) = \sum a_i \overline{x_i}$ is an isometric isomorphism.

> We use $ℝ$ but for $\Bbb C$ one just has to find a proper replacement for 'sgn'. Note that  $$ |\phi(a)(x)| = \left|\sum a_i x_i\right| \leq ‖a‖_{c_0} ‖ x‖_{\ell^1}$$ so that $‖\phi(a)‖_{c_0^*}\leq ‖a‖_{c_0}$; also, define $x^n∈ c_0$ with $‖x^n‖_{c_0} = 1$ by $$ x_i^n = (\text{sgn } a_i) \Bbb 1_{i\le n}$$ Then $|\phi(a)(x^n)| = \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|$, so $‖\phi(a)‖_{c_0^*} \geq \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|$ for every $n$. Send $n→∞$ to get that $\phi$ is an isometry. Isometries are injective; so now one has to prove its surjective. Pick some $T∈ c_0^*$ and consider the sequence $t=(T(e_i))_{i=1}^\infty$;  were this sequence in $\ell^1$, then by linearity and continuity, $$\phi(t)(a)=\sum T(e_i)a_i = T(\sum a_i e_i) = T(a)$$ i.e. $\phi(t) = T$. Now note that 
> $$\sum_{i=0}^n |t_i| = \sum_{i=0}^n T(e_i) \text{sgn }(t_i) = T(\sum_{i=0}^n [\text{sgn }t_i] e_i) \leq ‖T‖_{c_0^*} ‖([\text{sgn }t_i] e_i)\Bbb 1_{i\leq n}‖_{c_0} = ‖T‖_{c_0^*}  $$ 
>
>  which finishes the proof.

Comment: Well It's cauchy so it has a limit so I guess for each $k$ we could let our limit in $c_0$ be the sequence whose $k^{th}$ entry is this

Comment: Also, could you give an explicit example of why the limit $a$ fails?

Comment: Your limit isn't well defined, it depends on the $K$ (and therefore $\epsilon$) you choose: its not $a$, its $a^{ε}$. Writing the argument in full detail you see that you don't have a limit.

( In addition your action of $(x_n)$ doesn't satisfy  $\langle (x_n), -(a_n)⟩ = -  \langle (x_n), (a_n)⟩$ )

Comment: Ah, of course.

& to fix the action should I conjugate one of the two?

Comment: conjugate? You aren't working in $\Bbb C$ are you? The problem is the modulus.

Comment: these are complex-valued sequences... so should it be $$(x_n) : (a_n) \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n\overline{a_n}?$$

Comment: You say that but you wrote $(x_n) : c_0 → \Bbb R$. In the complex case, that is the right answer. (And coincidentally also the real case)

Comment: Whoops, a typo indeed. 

So, could you provide a **brief** hint in regards to how to show that all such linear functionals arise this way?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are nearly there, pick some $T∈ c_0^*$ and just do it.

Comment: Well that's where I'm a bit at a loss, how do I do "it"? If I know $T: (a_n) \mapsto \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, how do I deconstruct it into a sequence in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$? Maybe by considering $T((0, \ldots, 0, a_n ,0, \ldots, 0))$ for each $n$?

Comment: $T(∑a_ie_i) = ∑a_i T(e_i)$  [Check convergence; also of your limit in the first part] so we are led to consider the sequence $(T(e_i))_{i=1}^∞ $. Suppose it was not $\ell^1$, and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter yes.

Comment: Alright I can take it from here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter I found a quick direct argument instead (have sketched it out in a spoiler tag in the answer).

Comment: I haven't scanned over the spoiler, but did you put the operator norm on $c_0^*$?

Comment: Yeah the norm induced by the one on $c_o$.

Comment: Again, haven't looked at your spoiler, but it would seem that the isometric part would come fairly easily, since $$\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_ix_i \leq \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |x_i| $$ when $a_i$ is the sequence in $c_0$ that makes $x_i$ positive and has entries with length $1$ for longer and longer finite truncations

In particular, the sup would make them equal

Comment: which I'm assuming should be something like $\frac{x_i}{|x_i|}$ in the complex case

Comment: @AnthonyPeter yes

Comment: I just finished a proof by contradiction. What took me so long was that I was forgetting the dual space of a hilbert space implies all linear functionals are continuous and therefore bounded; without this I had nothing to contradict. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter right, it is important to note that we aren't talking about the algebraic dual :) Congrats

Comment: I don't see why $(T(e_n))_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ defines a sequence in $\ell^1$. I tried arguing by contradiction as you suggested, but I couldn't see how to arrive at the contradiction.

Comment: @user193319 it has been many years and I don’t remember a thing. I will try to think a little but no promises...

Comment: @user193319 sorry this has taken so long, but: the proof I have in the spoiler shows in the last centered mathematics that the $\ell^1$ norm is controlled by the operator norm of $T$. The contradiction argument was probably a little unnatural and I still cannot remember.