# $c_0$ is not weakly sequentially complete

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I want to prove that $c_0$ is not weakly sequentially complete.

First I considererd the sequence given by $x_n = (e_{n,k})_{n,k}$ where $e_{n,k} = 1$ if $k \leq n$ and $e_{n,k} = 0$ if $k > n$. Now I recently proved that

> $(x_n)_n \subset c_0$, $x_n \to x$ weakly iff $(x_n)_n$ is norm bounded in $c_0$ and $\pi_m(x_n) \to \pi_m(x)$  $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\pi_m$ is the canonical projection.

From this we say that the $\pi_m(x_n) \to \pi_m(x)$ can fail, and thus $x_n \not \to x$ weakly.

But, I have strong reasons to believe that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, here I'm having some trouble.

> $(x_n)_n$ is weakly Cauchy if for all $x^* \in c_0^*$ $x^*(x_n)$ is Cauchy

So if $U$ is the set $U = \{x \in c_0 : |x^*(x)| < \epsilon, \ \forall x^*\}$

How can I prove that $x_n-x_m \in U$?

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that the dual of $c_0$ is (isometric isomorphic to) $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ (see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1529955/36150)), i.e. if $x^* \in c_0^*$ then $x^* = (x_k^*)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |x_k^*| < \infty$. Thus, for $x_n$ defined in your question,

$$\langle x^*, x_n \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^*.$$

As $x^* \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$, the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^*$ converges to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k^*$ as $n \to \infty$, and so $(\langle x^*,x_n \rangle)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy. As $x^* \in c_0^*$ is arbitrary, this proves that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset c_0$ is weakly Cauchy.